# creating a folder in android studio that can be accessed with the @ syntax

Tags: android, android-studio

For e.g. a string resource can be accessed by it's name value and declaring it's resource folder like: `@string/some_name`. I'd like to do these for audio and image files with custom folders, how do I set this up for android studio to recognize it and so that I can access it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sorry, but that is not possible. You cannot invent your own resource types. That is limited to the development tools and, to an extent, the operating system.

Comment: I was searching in the android docs for the description as to where the assets folder and probably other folder are supposed to be placed. I found [this](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/res/AssetManager) but it doesn't describe the assets folder, found about this in the question marked duplicate. Do you know if there is a place in the official docs that have described it?

Comment: I was trying to get ahold of the doc because there could be other information like if we could(hopefully) create a subfolder structure or something like that

Comment: @juztcode: You can set up whatever directory structure you want inside of `assets/`. You then use `AssetManager` and its `open()` method to get an `InputStream` on a particular asset.